# How do I access a virtual directory from a WCF service that is not running on the same server as the virtual directory?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service called "SQLInterfaceLibrary" that is running on a machine via WcfSvcHost.exe. I can call all of its endpoints using WcfTestClient.exe by connecting to the URI "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/SQLInterfaceLibrary/mex". In fact, I can even connect to it directly from a C# application by using the "References.cs" file that I generate by calling SvcUtil.exe. However, the requirements of my project state that I must access an IIS virtual directory from this service. I found another StackOverflow post that suggests using the "HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath" function. However, when I call this from within my service, I get the following error:

"System.NullReferenceException:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

I think this is happening, because I am trying to access a virtual directory on a different machine. Can anyone with experience in WCF programming vouch for this? You don't need to provide a detailed explanation, just yes or no. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a IIS virtual directory in one machine, you can access using ip:port or dns of that machine. For your first test, allow all users and Directory browsing (then you can try from any web browser), check or disable temporally windows  firewall

Comment: Ah yes, it could be the firewall. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Great! Pls, you don't forget re-enable after your test.

Answer (score 0):

By default, wcf's httpcontext is null, you should set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to true in your web.config .

```
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

If  httpcontext is still null, you could add  AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to your service

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
public class CalculatorService : ICalculatorService
{
    public double Add(double a, double b)
    {
      HttpContext context=  HttpContext.Current;
      string dir =  Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful!